# Making a new array with Array's X keys' values

Tags: php, arrays

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Array
        (
            [summonerName] => FOX kfo
            [profileIcon] => 28
        )

    [2] => 2
    [3] => Array
        (
            [summonerName] => FOX Hard
            [profileIcon] => 7
        )

    [4] => 3
    [5] => Array
        (
            [summonerName] => FOX Froggen
            [profileIcon] => 4
        )

    [6] => 4
    [7] => Array
        (
            [summonerName] => FOX Keith
            [profileIcon] => 23
        )

    [8] => 5
    [9] => Array
        (
            [summonerName] => FOX Big
            [profileIcon] => 4
        )

    [10] => 6
    [11] => Array
        (
            [summonerName] => C9 Impact
            [profileIcon] => 7
        )

    [12] => 7
    [13] => Array
        (
            [summonerName] => C9 Meteos
            [profileIcon] => 4
        )

    [14] => 8
    [15] => Array
        (
            [summonerName] => C9 Jensen
            [profileIcon] => 4
        )

    [16] => 9
    [17] => Array
        (
            [summonerName] => C9 Sneaky
            [profileIcon] => 4
        )

    [18] => 10
    [19] => Array
        (
            [summonerName] => C9 Smoothie
            [profileIcon] => 4
        )

)
```

How to convert the array on above to this?

```
  Array 
(
    [0] => FOX kfo
    [1] => FOX Hard
    [2] => FOX Froggen
    [3] => FOX Keith
    [4] => FOX Big
    [5] => C9 Impact
    [6] => C9 Meteos
    [7] => C9 Jensen
    [8] => C9 Sneaky
    [9] => C9 Smoothie
)
```

I want to make an array with all `[summonerName]`s.

I could not find a good title that explains that situation since my main language is not english. I didn't know how to explain that in title. If you have better idea for title, you can edit.

The question is marked as duplicate but i couldnt make it work by looking at answers in the given link. :(

Answer (score 0):

array build something like this

```
        <?php   


    $new_array =array();
    foreach($array_value as $key=>$row)
    {

        if(isset($row['summonerName']))
        {

        $new_array[]=$row['summonerName'];

        }


    }

    print_r($new_array);
    ?>
```